# Why read data from a text file C#

Tags: c#

I'm learning C # right now and I've gotten to a point with console applications where I'm about to learn how to read data from a text file. Before I start learning how to make a program do this I've been trying to find out why you would want to do this. I always feel that if I understand why I'm doing something then I can better understand the benefits of it and give it the time it deserves when being taught. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could  tell me when and how you would use something like reading data from a text file and what the benefits are? I have been looking for a couple of weeks now and can't find anything and I need to get started. Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are many reasons: log files, data files, settings files, xml files, html files, scripts, …...too many to list.

Comment: -1 Looking for a couple of weeks for the benefits of why people write programs that read text files. Why dont you just google `System.IO.File ReadAllText`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the most basic level, you read data from a text file because the data you need is stored in a text file (as opposed to a database or retrieved from a web service call).

Why is data stored in text files? Many reasons:

1. Text files are amongst the easiest files to create and process. Un*x comes with a whole plethora of tools for creating, searching, filtering and modifying them and many have been ported to Windows.
2. Little can go wrong with text files. Indexes can get corrupted on databases. Database file formats vary from one database to the next and so on. A simple CSV (comma separated variable) file is a form of text file that is almost universally supported.
3. Editing a text file is easy. No need for heavy graphical editors. You can use anything from Notepad to vim, Emacs or Sublime.
4. Programmatically, text files do not require heavy libraries to access.

These days, data is stored in text files usually for:

1. Configuration (since little can go wrong and it is easy to edit)
2. Logging (since they are easy to create and view)
3. Sharing data between systems (since they are a lowest common denominator). Remember that HTTP, SMTP and many common Internet standards are based on text.
4. Historical or legacy systems that could be updated to use a database or something more appropriate.

Comment: Which [crummy] database are *you* using? :|

Answer (score 0):

I'm approaching your question from a different and more fundamental POV, as in why does the concept of files exist, as opposed to other guys who're answering it from files vs. DB or modern-day uses of files POV.

At some point, many applications need to save their state or data to some persistent storage, i.e. a place where data could survive even after the application is closed or the computer is shutdown. One such place is a disk where can hold files in it without requiring power supply once that it has written the file. The next time computer is started and our application is run, we can read our last saved data from that file and continue our work from that point onward. One example is a Word document. You create a new document today, write some part of it and then want to take a break. Till now the contents of your document are in your computer's RAM (fast but volatile memory) and need to be saved to a persistent medium (your hard disk normally). So you choose Save command from within Word application, give it a file name and Word will use file-writing functions behind-the-scene to save these contents to a file. Once done, you can now safely close your application and/or your machine. The next time you want to edit this document, you start Word, choose Open command and select the file. Once again, Word will use file-reading functions to read file contents into memory.

In a similar fashion you'll use file reading and writing functions in C# (`System.IO.File` has all that you'll need). In the start you may file `System.IO.File.ReadAllText()` and `System.IO.File.WriteAllText()` fast and easy to learn and experiment with. Later you'll see that text content isn't always the format that one needs to store and read and that some content needs to be stored in binary format. A very much related concept here is that streams, but I don't want to make it too difficult for you at this point. Just keep moving and you'll figure things out one by one.

Answer (score -1):

Let me tell you in the simple way. Let's say you have a game. Your game has a level score, player properties(clothing ,height..bla bla) and the player wants to start from the last point and there is no way that your application could know.

So we need another information source for the game to start from the last session! The easiest way is text file.

Comment: lol. one textfile per user ;) very funny

Comment: @naveen i am sure you have no idea what i am talking about

Comment: very true :) i do not.

Comment: @naveen let say u have a game and ,,,and i reached the 3rd stage...so ,,where did you store this information?...